# Is This Proper Use of GOTO in C#

Tags: c#, goto

I'm tracing some code, and a list is sent to the below, to remove certain items from the list.

Is this the proper way to use the goto? Is it even necessary? Wouldn't you just edit the second if to be an else if, and continue processing the list without the need for a goto? (This is the first time I've ever seen goto outside of BASIC.)

```
public static IList<ClientEntity> FilterNoNeedSendBackToClients(IList<ClientEntity> src)
    {
        if (src == null)
            return null;
    checkAB01:
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Count; i++)
        {
            ClientEntity info = src[i];
            if (info.ProductNumber != null && info.ProductNumber.ToLower().Trim().Length > 0
                    &&
                    info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 != null && info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01.Value == true
                )
            {
                src.Remove(info);
                goto checkAB01;
            }

            if ((info.PartnerContract == null || info.PartnerContract.Trim().Length == 0)
                &&
                (info.ProductNumber == null || info.ProductNumber.Trim().Length == 0))
            {
                src.Remove(info);
                goto checkAB01;
            }
        }
        return src;
    }
```

Comment: There is *no* proper way to use `goto` in C#. Every use of it is, by definition, a code smell.

Comment: Seems terribly inefficient to me. Looks like it loops through from 0..N until it removes something, then starts again from 0..N (now 1 less) until it removes something, and so on. If it finds nothing to remove, it returns. Better to just do a reverse for loop removing entries then returning.

Comment: STAY AWAY FROM GOTO's where I use to work the boss would say if they say GOTO's in Code.. they would FIRE YOU ON THE SPOT...

Comment: GOTOs actually WORK in C#?  Some things humans were never meant to know...

Comment: `goto case n` can be useful in a switch statement since C# does not allow cases to fall through to the next one.

Comment: there are some useful uses for goto, as dmitry has stated. dont bash it just because you dont know how to use it correctly. Although, general rule of thumb is that it will make your code harder to follow. I also use it to break nested loops sometimes.

Comment: ... And switch statements are another code smell; a long block of code with many entry points that has to change every time the number of possible input values changes. They have their uses but you must consider whether another pattern/construct is better.

Comment: @DmitryStarosta `goto case` is technically a different keyword than a `goto`.  It's like saying `yield return` is a proper way of using `return` inside of a method (if you're one of those people that think doing that is wrong).  Despite the similarities, they're entirely different.

Comment: Also, use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info.ProductNumber)` instead of what you have now. Also, what type is `info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01`? I think you can use `info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 == (bool?)true` instead (it's a nullable boolean, `bool?`).

Comment: @caesay: `goto`'s advantage, in unmanaged languages, is performance; it's usually translated 1:1 to a "jmp" ASM command. If you are programming in a managed environment, you have given up on the level of performance that necessitates kludgy micro-optimized code; you are instead focused on *correct* code, that is well-organized, easy to read and understand, and thus to maintain. `goto` is, by definition, *never* correct code because any use of it is a red flag that any other logic constructs surrounding it are not well-organized, and thus the code is hard to read and understand.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, that was what I thought at first, but since I came to C# with no formal training, I was wondering if there was a hidden thing where the loop was remembering it's place. That and the GOTO were driving me nuts.

Comment: The only thing "hidden" in a for loop like this is the exact order the three statements specified at the top of the loop get executed; when you enter the loop, the first statement is executed (usually initializing the counter), then the second statement is executed (to determine if we should run the loop even once). After the first loop, the third statement (counter modifier) is executed for the first time. The use of the goto and label basically resets the for loop every time, because each entry after the jump to the label is treated as if it were the first time the loop had been entered.

Comment: @Servy, according to MSDN they are considered the same statement (unlike return and yield return). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I think you're all giving too much importance to this. What really matters in terms of readability and maintenance is things like class relationships and proper inheritance trees. Those are the things that give you a high-level view of a program. Gotos are always used in IMPLEMENTATION CODE, so they have no real impact on readability. Anyway, there ARE some cases where gotos are appropriate, it's just that the other control alternatives (if, while, for, etc) are special-purpose and therefore better. But there are situations not covered by those alternatives, and that's where goto comes in.

Comment: @user1610015 - Name one. I've been coding in C# for about 9 years now, and have not yet found a situation that required `goto` that wouldn't be just as easily done with a "proper" loop structure. I coded in C++ for 5 years before that, and it was a code smell even then. And you sound like you've never had to go back and comprehend "implementation code" in order to make some surgical change in behavior; a "high-level" view of a program's great, but when a bug can be as simple as a single character out of place I place a very high value on low-level readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about LINQ?

```
public static IList<ClientEntity> FilterNoNeedSendBackToClients(IList<ClientEntity> src)
{
    if (src == null)
        return null;

    return (from info in src.AsEnumerable<ClientEntity>()
            where !(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info.ProductNumber) &&
                    info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 == (bool?)true)
            where !(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(info.PartnerContract) &&
                    String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info.ProductNumber))
            select info).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This code does not modify the original list (which could be a good thing).

Comment: The predicate for the first `where` clause would seem like it could do well from an application of DeMorgan's laws. It's also  unnecessary to compare to `true`

Comment: @Iridium It's silly to _both_ say `.Value` on a nullable bool and _then_ compare to `true`. But the entire condition (including `HasValue` check) can be written `info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 == (bool?)true`. The explicit cast to `bool?` is redundant but helps the reader of the code a lot.

Comment: I just copied what was in the original question. Although it would seem like a nullable bool, I didnt want to make that assumption.

Comment: I've applied this, and it works, but the better thing to do is to make the original sql server statement (concatenated strings!) into a stored procedure which does all this for me, and negates the use of this completely.

Comment: Who would write their own class with a property (or field) with the name `Value` of a type that is either `bool`, `bool?`, or implicitly convertible to/from `bool` or `bool?`? I know it is possible in principle, but I'm pretty sure `CancelledByReliantSyncAB01` is a nullable boolean. I don't know why many people first check a nullable for `HasValue`, then unwrap the nullable and compare to a specific value, in cases where they can just use a [lifted compare operator](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3A_14.2.7_Lifted_operators).

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't a proper way to use goto, it's just a substitute for someone who doesn't know how to properly remove items from a list. (Iterate backwards to prevent skipping elements)

```
public static IList<ClientEntity> FilterNoNeedSendBackToClients(IList<ClientEntity> src)
{
    if (src == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = src.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ClientEntity info = src[i];
        if (info.ProductNumber != null && info.ProductNumber.ToLower().Trim().Length > 0
                &&
                info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 != null && info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01.Value == true
            )
        {
            src.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        if ((info.PartnerContract == null || info.PartnerContract.Trim().Length == 0)
            &&
            (info.ProductNumber == null || info.ProductNumber.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            src.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    return src;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think whoever wrote this code did not know how to remove items from the iterated collection. The reason for those gotos was that once an item is deleted, the collection becomes smaller which can cause iteration errors.

A better day to do this is to do a reverse for loop. This way you do not have to reiterate through the whole list after a deletion. The code below will work just fine.

```
for (int i = src.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    src.Remove(src[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this is a poor usage of `goto` (which should *rarely*, if ever, be used)

Overall though, the implementation is terribly inefficient. Looks like it loops through from 0..N until it removes something, then starts again from 0..N (now 1 less) until it removes something, and so on.  Even worse, the `Remove` call *again* goes from 0..N looking for that item to remove.

If it finds nothing to remove, it returns. Better to just do a reverse for loop removing entries with `RemoveAt` then returning.

```
public static IList<ClientEntity> FilterNoNeedSendBackToClients(IList<ClientEntity> src)
{
    if (src == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = src.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ClientEntity info = src[i];
        if (info.ProductNumber != null && info.ProductNumber.ToLower().Trim().Length > 0
            &&
            info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 != null && info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01.Value == true)
        {
            src.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        else if ((info.PartnerContract == null || info.PartnerContract.Trim().Length == 0)
            &&
            (info.ProductNumber == null || info.ProductNumber.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            src.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    return src;
}
```

Also, I added an `elseif` there: seems dangerous to do *another* `if` check that could potentially be true and try to re-remove the same item (especially after changing the indices).

EDIT: If we're talking about readable usable code, I'd move out the checks to a separate method anyway:

```
public static IList<ClientEntity> FilterNoNeedSendBackToClients(IList<ClientEntity> src)
{
    if (src == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = src.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (ShouldClientNotSendBack(src[i]))
            src.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    return src;
}

private static bool ShouldClientNotSendBack(ClientEntity info)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info.ProductNumber) && info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info.PartnerContract))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Might even consider tweaking that `ShouldClientNotSendBack` method and/or name (perhaps even move the two sets of `if` checks to individual methods with clear names), but this I think is a significant improvement overall.

EDITx2: In fact, I would strongly consider usage of the method. The method is clearly returning an `IList<ClientEntity>` while taking in an input collection, which typically communicates to developers that this is *creating a new list* when in fact it's actually **mutating** the existing list and returning the same list instance. Either have it return a new list (thus you should change the loop code to add to a new list instead of removing from the existing) or remove the return type so it's more apparent that it's mutating the passed list argument.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in my comment, there is no "proper" way to use `goto` in C#. The keyword is, by its very definition, a kludge; it's a throwback to C/C++, which included it as a "just in case", should a developer want to translate line-by-line a program in ASM or BASIC or other language without defined code blocks, which hide the "jumps" used to get into and between them. Any algorithm that uses it can be refactored to not have to do so, and the resulting algorithm will be more readable.

In this case:

```
public static IList<ClientEntity> FilterNoNeedSendBackToClients(IList<ClientEntity> src)
{
    if (src == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = src.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        ClientEntity info = src[i];
        if (info.ProductNumber != null && info.ProductNumber.ToLower().Trim().Length > 0
                &&
                info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01 != null && info.CancelledByReliantSyncAB01.Value == true
            )
        {
            src.Remove(info);
            continue;
        }

        if ((info.PartnerContract == null || info.PartnerContract.Trim().Length == 0)
            &&
            (info.ProductNumber == null || info.ProductNumber.Trim().Length == 0))
        {
            src.Remove(info);
            continue;
        }
    }
    return src;
}
```

As Chris Sinclair's answer shows, because of the "either/or" implicit structure of the conditionals in the loop, the `continue` statements aren't necessary, but I like them because they show the coder that nothing from that point to the end of the loop will be run, without them having to read the rest of it to determine that.

If you wanted to, you could run through the list front to back, and if an item is removed, decrement `i` before continuing so that the loop will maintain its current position in the list. Some may say not to do it this way because the manipulation of the counter makes it harder to understand the algorithm (and because determining the count of the list on each iteration is slightly slower), but it's still far better in both performance and readability than the `goto`.